# How do I group foreign table columns under a distinct table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

my index.php file currently looks like this:

```
commenter1
----------
    replier1 -> commenter1

commenter2
----------
    replier4 -> commenter2  

commenter2
----------
    replier12 -> commenter2
```

But the result I really want is this:

```
commenter1
----------
    replier1 -> commenter1

commenter2
----------
    replier4 -> commenter2  
    replier12 -> commenter2
```

To explain my issue, I don't know how to group my "repliers" together underneath their corresponding "commenters".

Can someone please show me how to do this with my current code?

```
<?php
$query = $conn->query("
    SELECT comments.*, replies.*, users.username
    FROM comments
    INNER JOIN replies
    ON comments.comid = replies.repcomid
    INNER JOIN users
    ON comments.comuserid = users.userid
    WHERE comments.comrqid = {$rqid}
    ORDER BY comments.comid DESC;
");
$comsreps = [];
while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
  $comsreps[] = $row;
}
?>

<?php foreach($comsreps as $comsrep): ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $comsrep->username; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="fxrp">
        <div>
            <?php echo $comsrep->repfromname; ?> -->
            <?php echo $comsrep->reptoname; ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php echo $comsrep->repcomment; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to deal with this is to keep track of the last username output, and if the current one is the same, don't output it again. For example:

```
<?php 
    $last_username = '';
    foreach($comsreps as $comsrep):
        if ($comsrep->username != $last_username): ?>
        <div>
            <?php echo $comsrep->username; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
          $last_username = $comsrep->username; ?> 
    <div class="fxrp">
        <div>
            <?php echo $comsrep->repfromname; ?> -->
            <?php echo $comsrep->reptoname; ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php echo $comsrep->repcomment; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @misner3456 is this what you were looking for? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry about that. There were so many issues with my code so I was trying to get this to work with my current code. But technically your answer resolved my issue. I'm marking yours as best answer. Thanks so much for the help, really sorry for the late response!

Comment: @misner3456 no problem at all, I just wanted to check that you didn't need more help.